# Numpy Matrix field multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 vectors containing matrices, say `x = [A, B, C, ..]` and `y = [D, E, F, ..]`.

How can I calculate the product `z = [A*D, B*E, C*F, ..]` the most performant way using numpy?

Both `x` and `y` contain the same number of matrices and all matrices have the same shape, e.g both `x` and `y` could have the shape `(1000,3,3)`. The result of the calculation should therefore also result in the same shape of `(1000,3,3)`.

Edit:
For clarification, A*B should denote the *dot product* of A and B.

Comment: If the linked question is not a duplicate, please post sufficient information in your question to make it meaningful. Right now it's fairly vague and up for a lot of different interpretations

Comment: `the most performant way` - how are you doing it that isn't satisfactory?